# iCloud is full, but no way to delete photos/backups anything

Tags: iphone, icloud

i got an email that my iCloud was full. I went into phone settings and noticed that a lot of things i previously disabled were now enabled so i disabled them again ( backups, photos)

it seems that disabling it did not remove anything from iCloud because it's still full.

i logged into iCloud.com and i can see my storage is full but i can't find any way to delete my existing stuff.

Comment: Try to delete your iCloud backup. Do a backup via iTunes. Try on your iPhone: Settings -> General -> Storage- & iCloud usage -> Manage storage -> See your backup? Choose it. Scroll down. Press delete Backup and confirm. Now move back and delete those data you don't need (Documents & data). The next time you get an iCloud backup you should be all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is so confusing! even if i turned off all the services that still didn't do anything.

i finally found it.

> settings > icloud > storage > manage storage > start turning **** off and it will actually delete on iCloud.

it was storing all kinds of things i never authorized! like "health data" podcasts, photos.. this really sucks.